# GCC baremetal inline-assembly SI register not playing nicely with pointers

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, 16-bit, bare-metal

Well, this is obviously a beginner's question, but this is my first attempt at making an operating system in `C` (Actually, I'm almost entirely new to `C`.. I'm used to `asm`) so, why exactly is this not valid? As far as I know, a `pointer` in `C` is just a `uint16_t` used to point to a certain area in memory, right (or a `uint32_t` and that's why it's not working)?
I've made the following kernel ("I've already made a bootloader and all in assembly to load the resulting KERNEL.BIN file):

`kernel.c`

```
void printf(char *str)
{
__asm__(
"mov    si, %0\n"
"pusha\n"
"mov    ah, 0x0E\n"
".repeat:\n"
"lodsb\n"
"cmp    al, 0\n"
"je .done\n"
"int    0x10\n"
"jmp    .repeat\n"
".done:\n"
"popa\n"
:
: "r" (str)
);
return;
}

int main()
{
char *msg = "Hello, world!";
printf(msg);
__asm__("jmp $");
return 0;
}
```

I've used the following command to compile it `kernel.c`:

`gcc kernel.c -ffreestanding -m32 -std=c99 -g -O0 -masm=intel -o kernel.bin`

which returns the following error:

`kernel.c:3: Error: operand type mismatch for 'mov'`

Why exactly might be the cause of this error?

Comment: Gonna give you a piece of advice. You can poo poo it if you wish, but if you are new to this kind of thing, the worst thing you can do is doing inline assembler. Very easy to get it wrong, you need proper input, outputs and clobbers to cover everything that is changed. If you want to write in assembler I recommend writing those functions in a separate assembler file free of the _C_ code.

Comment: If you use inline assembler use it sparingly. Only use it where necessary and let the _C_ code do the work for you (including loops etc).

Comment: Even experienced _C_ developers who attempt GCCs extended inline assembler can create code that appears to work and then at some point in the future doesn't act the way it should when the _C_ optimizer reduces everything. If you don't know what you are doing it is a load of butthurt waiting to happen.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you, but I'm not really new to this kind of thing. I've done inline assembly before, and made a couple crappy OS's in assembly, and I understand how it works :) I just don't understand why there's a conflict between SI and a pointer.

Comment: If you had done this before you might realize that you are using a 32-bit compiler to generate 16-bit code which is another problem here.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, I've definitely heard to (and do) use it sparingly... at such low level, there are some times when this is necessary.

Comment: @MichaelPetch And to that, you would be correct... I am new to using C for 16-bit code, so I didn't even think about that.. does GCC even have 16-bit capabilities?

Comment: Well in 32-bit code registers are by default 4 bytes wide. Imagine if the address of `str` is passed in a 32-bit register.let us assume the compiler picks `EAX`. Now imagine what happens when substituion occurs. - `mov si, eax` would be generated. Notice a problem there?

Comment: GCC has limited 16-bit capabilities. Its a gigantic hack. And if you get it working, the real mode code will only run on a 386 processor or higher (or anything that emulates one)

Comment: If you want to go down the dangerous path of GCC 16-bit code you are going to want to look at using `.code16gcc` directive and compiling with the `-m16` option . But fair warning, I discourage this. If you really want to write 16-bit code I'd suggest OpenWatcom or Bruce's C compiler.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Huge problem indeed... Would it work if I casted the pointer to a `uint16_t` value?

EDIT: Also tried `-m16`... still gives same error oddly.

Comment: If you want to use 16-bit address in that template you'd have to force the `%0` operand to operate on the 16-bit register that GCC chose. To do that you can use `%w0` . Change `"mov    si, %0\n"` to `"mov    si, %w0\n"` . The `w` says to treat that template parameter as 16-bits

Comment: You'll want to add at the top of each of your 16-bit _C_ files (or a common header) this line: `__asm__(".code16gcc");` and I mean literally at the top before any function. You will then want to use `-m16` rather than `-m32` option. You'll also want to exclude the standard libraries  when building with _GCC_. Your command to build would look like `gcc kernel.c -ffreestanding -nostdlib -m16 -std=c99 -g -O0 -masm=intel -o kernel.bin`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Well, I found the problem... on top of that, I realised I tried to shove a literal into `SI`... To get a literal into `SI` you have to `mov` it into a general purpose register first, which is basic assembly knowledge. (facepalm) Thank you very much :)

Comment: As I said you want to change `"mov si, %0\n"` to `"mov si, %w0\n"` . Using inline templates is likely going to kill you.

Comment: A month or so ago I hacked up a simple 16-bit bootloader written with _GCC_ that printed `Hello World` to the display. You can find that code here: http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/ircasm/gccboot/ . It used int 10/ah-0xe to write to the screen.

Answer (score 2):

As Michael Petch already explained, you use inline assembly only for the absolute minimum of code that cannot be done in C. For the rest there is inline assembly, but you have to be extremely careful to set the constraints and clobber list right.

Let always GCC do the job of passing the values in the right register and just specify in which register the values should be.

For your problem you probably want to do something like this

```
#include <stdint.h>

void print( const char *str )
{
  for ( ; *str; str++) {
    __asm__ __volatile__("int $0x10" : : "a" ((int16_t)((0x0E << 8) + *str)), "b" ((int16_t)0) : );
  }
}
```

EDIT: Your assembly has the problem that you try to pass a pointer in a 16 bit register. This cannot work for 32 bit code, as 32 bit is also the pointer size. 
If you in case want to generate 16 bit real-mode code, there is the -m16 option. But that does not make GCC a true 16 bit compiler, it has its limitations. Essentially it issues a .code16gcc directive in the code.

Comment: Hmm, strange that there don't seem to be separate constraints for AL and AH.  There is a `"Q"` constraint for registers that have an RH sub-register (A,C,D, or B), but none for specific H registers.  Nice workaround.  I might have used `|` instead of `+`, though.

Comment: Also, it would be good if you at least summarized the comments, and point out that pointers are in fact 32-bit when you compile with `-m32` to generate 32-bit code like the OP is doing, which answers one of the key parts of the question.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Indeed, I think there is constraint for ah. But since that one is special (as compared to the EAX, AX or AL which is auto selected from the integer size), it makes in my opinion slightly more complicated to understand. That is why I used the C approach.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I added the edit on the SI size problem. I overlooked this, thanks. I mostly "ignored" the comments as they are largely on OS writing and 16/32 bit issues, which was not part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply use 16bit assembly instructions on 32-bit pointers and expect it to work.  `si` is the lower 16bit of the `esi` register (which is 32bit).

gcc -m32 and -m16 both use 32-bit pointers.  -m16 just uses address-size and operand-size prefixes to do mostly the same thing as normal -m32 mode, but running in real mode.

If you try to use 16bit addressing in a 32bit application you'll drop the high part of your pointers, and simply go to a *different place*.

Just try to read a book on intel 32bit addressing modes, and *protected mode*, and you'll see that many things are different on that mode.

(and if you try to switch to 64bit mode, you'll see that everything changes again)

A bootloader is something different as normally, cpu reset forces the cpu to begin in 16bit real mode.  This is completely different from 32bit protected mode, which is one of the first things the operating system does.  Bootloaders work in 16bit mode, and there, pointers are 16bit wide (well, not, 20bits wide, when the proper segment register is appended to the address)

Comment: operand-size and address-size prefixes let 16-bit code use 32-bit registers, including 32-bit addressing modes.  `gcc -m16` does that, still using 32-bit addresses and integers.  It's super-ugly, and bloated, but it is technically valid 16-bit code that will run on 386 and later.  It might even be usable for something if you set up the segment registers properly.  I agree with the general sentiment that it doesn't seem like a good idea, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes, but this is part of the 32bit addressing.  Assemblers can put 16bit prefixes if you try to reference the `SI` register (instead of `ESI`) and force a 16bit address.  In normal assembler application programming, you put the default behaviour in the program header (after assembling some addressing mode directives)  If you don't, you'll get 32bit protected mode, with 32bit data and 32bit default addresses, and if you are on a 64bit platform, you'll get 32bit data and 64bit addresses as default in linux, and freebsd (at least).  Don't know windows applications environment.

Comment: Operand-size prefixes on single instructions don't change between protected-mode and real-mode.  They just change the operand-size: paging stays enabled (or disabled), and segment registers keep their meaning (as indices into the GDT / LDT, or as shifted-by-4 additions to create a linear address).

Comment: Modern OSes don't even have an option to start processes in 16-bit mode, because they run the kernel in long mode.  This means VM86 mode isn't available.  I didn't think it was possible to run a process in compat mode with the default operand size set to 16 bits.  I thought it had to be 32 bits when the CPU was in compat mode or long mode.  I think if there was a reasonable way for processes to run in long mode with the default address set to 32-bit, the x32 ABI would use it.  But the x32 ABI often has to use address-size prefixes to get 32-bit address size, so I assume it can't be done.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I think the problem here is somebody is trying to program in assembly for a modern operating system, using his knowledge from 16bit real mode assembly, as he says *I've already made a bootloader and all in assembly to load the resulting KERNEL.BIN file*.  You are clearly not the target audience for my comment.  I know prefixes don't change, but they can be *automatically* inserted by the assembler if you *know what you are doing* and not being aware this is not the normal mode selected for your application.

Comment: Yes, I was just nit-picking about the way you were explaining it.  The OP's actual inline asm is total garbage, and can't be fixed without a total rewrite with a different approach.

Comment: And if you are able to run `dosemu` at least,  it runs in `VM86` mode.

Comment: I try to explain this to a newcomer to C from real mode assembly.

Comment: VM86 mode requires a hypervisor and hardware virtualization, if the kernel is in long mode.  VM86 is only available in legacy mode (32-bit kernel).

Comment: I think your first sentence doesn't say exactly what you meant. "You simply cannot use..." means "you can't ever do this, no matter what you try, the answer is a simple no/never".  But I think you meant to say "You cannot simply use", which means "You can't just do that and expect it to work.  It might be possible, but with complications".  So this whole comment discussion might have started from a lost-in-translation issue, which I only just realized >.<

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123407/discussion-between-luis-colorado-and-peter-cordes).