# How can I use C char arrays under real mode

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, assembly, char

I'm developing a bare-bone operating system in real mode. I have written my bootloader under assembly. But I want to write my kernel with C language. So far everything was nice but I notice that when I use char arrays (not pointers) for function parameters, they are not working. For example when I use:

```
puts("Hello, World!");
```

or,

```
char *ptr = "Hello, World!";
puts(ptr);
```

these are working. But when I do this:

```
char s[]="Hello, World!";
puts(s);
```

It's give me nothing. I want to know, why this happens and how can I use char arrays in this way?
Also this is my "puts" function:

```
void puts(char* s){
for(; *s!=0; s++)
    asm volatile ("int $0x10": : "a"(0x0e00 | *s));
}
```

EDIT:
I'm compiling the using GCC with:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -Os -nostdlib -m16 -march=i386 -ffreestanding -o kernel.bin -Wl,--nmagic,--script=raw_image.ld kernel.c
```

And this is the linker script:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary);
ENTRY(main);
SECTIONS
{
. = 0x0000;
.text :
{
    *(.text);
}
.data :
{
    *(.data);
    *(.bss);
    *(.rodata);
}
}
```

Also these are the web sites I used:

[Building DOS COM files using GCC](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2014/12/09/)

[Writing Bootloader in Assembly and C](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664165/Writing-a-boot-loader-in-Assembly-and-C-Part)

Comment: Strictly speaking the, `ptr` of  *ptr = "Hello, World!"; is a `const char*` type. Could that be something to do with it?

Comment: @PaulR GCC compiler give correct output.

Comment: Please give us enough code to replicate the issue.

Comment: @M.SChaudhari: of course it does, but how does that help ? Did you read the whole question ?

Comment: It seems like you didn't make sure that `bx` is zeroed out. Could you try to ensure that?

Comment: @FUZxxl BX is already zeroed out.

Comment: @B.Kaan How do you ensure that? The caller could fill BX with any value, if it is nonzero, your output goes to an invisible page.

Comment: @FUZxxl Oh, you are right. But it's not the problem. Even BX zero nothing changes also when I use char arrays in any function parameters (for example: strlen) they are not working..

Comment: Could it be that `ds` and `ss` points to two different segments? char arrays are [created on the stack](https://godbolt.org/g/z6nbKK)

Comment: @MargaretBloom Wow! It seems thats the problem.. While debugging the code it does "mov ax, ds:dx" but it should be "mov ax, ss:dx". Because when I hex dumped  ss:dx it gives me the correct array. Thanks a lot. But I have a another question, sir. I want to use stack 64 KB in size. But while ds and ss points to same segments I've no 64 KB stack size. So that in my case they can't be in the same segment. What should I do?

Comment: @B.Kaan GCC is not really suitable for 16 bit code IIRC exactly because it doesn't handle far pointers.  Maybe someone more expert can give you better pieces of advice. You *could* try setting `ss` into [unreal mode](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/x86/3679/real-vs-protected-modes/19574/unreal-mode#t=201609141127062051752) and giving `esp` a higher value, but that has its drawbacks.

Comment: If you want to write 16-bit C code I recommend OpenWatcom (and the JLOC linker) or Bruce's C Compiler. Someone had a very [similar SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482526/gcc-baremetal-inline-assembly-si-register-not-playing-nicely-with-pointers#comment66284182_39482526) . If you want my advice it is in the comments. If you want an example of pseduo 16-bit code GCC code running as a bootloader that prints "Hello World" you could look at  a hackish GCC (I don't recommend it) example I wrote here:  http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/ircasm/gccboot/

Comment: Open Watcom is ideal because it does allow its own form of inline assembler, produces 16-bit code, and understands real mode segments, far pointers etc.

Comment: One other word of advice. If you use GCC's hackish pseudo 16-bit code it is best to have all your code running and loaded somewhere in the first 64kb of memory and all the segments set to 0.

Comment: I just read through that article on Code Project. There is some bad advice in that article, and assumptions that will lead to problems like the one you experienced here with stack vs data segment references. The code in my example (link) above deals with those pesky problems.

Comment: @Michael Petch Thank you very much.. I'll look at Open Watcom. I tried BCC but it uses K&R syntax so its a little annoying to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look at disassembler output for the resulting binary file. It might be that GCC targeting freestanding 386 did something unexpected with segments or whatever.

If that doesn't help much, you still have an option of using e.g. Bochs to run your OS there and use Bochs' integrated debugger to find out what actually happens when the code runs.

Comment: Good point re: gcc vs freestanding 386. For what it's worth, Boch's is happy to show you the disassembly in either format, all you have to do is ask! See here: http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html#AEN4067 Boch's debugger has saved my bacon _lots_ of times.